# Searching Word built-in method to list the most repeated words in the document

Tags: microsoft-word

I read [Allen Wyatt's website](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T011362_Automatically_Identifying_Repeated_Words.html) last updated Jan 18 2020, but he recommends downloading other programs.
Does Word have anything built-in?

> A standalone program—one not run as a Word add-in—is TextSTAT. It can read several types of files, including Word documents. It produces a detailed listing with all sorts of statistical summaries. Best of all, TextSTAT is free at:
>
> http://neon.niederlandistik.fu-berlin.de/en/textstat/
>
> If you'd like to "jump under the hood" and create your own macro to get the desired results, consider the discussion at a previous *WordTip*, located here:
>
> https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010761
>
> You could also benefit by examining how MVP Greg Maxey tackles the issue:
>
> https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/word_usage_and_frequency_report.html

Comment: What are you asking? “Does Word have a built-in feature to do it?” “Do any of these work”? Something else?

Comment: There is no such build-in feature to do this in Word. I think Allen Wyatt's macros are very helpful to determine word frequency in a word document. You can also get it from the page:[Determining Word Frequency](https://word.tips.net/T000879_Determining_Word_Frequency.html). Some 3rd-party add-in may be useful to the question. I find an old thread taking the similar question:[How to find a list of most repeated words/phrases in a document](https://www.proz.com/forum/cat_tools_technical_help/286169-how_to_find_a_list_of_most_repeated_words_phrases_in_a_document.html).

Comment: @yokki "Does Word have a built-in feature to do it?” Yes.

Comment: I would go with HerbGu_MSFT ' s comment in that case.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)
has been part of Word since the year 1993.
This ancient programming  language is very primitive and hard to use,
which is probably why you are asking here for help.

The actual method to use
[Allen Wyatt's VBA macro](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010761_Generating_a_Count_of_Word_Occurrences.html)
is pretty straight-forward and is described below.

It would perhaps be simpler, in addition to the steps below, to also see
in YouTube a video explaining the process step-by-step:
[Word - Generating a Count of Word Occurrences by Chris Menard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp_IO0JTyQQ).

The process described in the video is as follows:

- The document should be first saved as `.docm` to allow macros
- Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to enter the VBA editor
- Use menu *Insert > Module* and copy-paste the contents to be the following,
  to create a macro named `WordFrequency`:

  ```
    Sub WordFrequency()
        Const maxwords = 9000          'Maximum unique words allowed
        Dim SingleWord As String       'Raw word pulled from doc
        Dim Words(maxwords) As String  'Array to hold unique words
        Dim Freq(maxwords) As Integer  'Frequency counter for unique words
        Dim WordNum As Integer         'Number of unique words
        Dim ByFreq As Boolean          'Flag for sorting order
        Dim ttlwds As Long             'Total words in the document
        Dim Excludes As String         'Words to be excluded
        Dim Found As Boolean           'Temporary flag
        Dim j, k, l, Temp As Integer   'Temporary variables
        Dim ans As String              'How user wants to sort results
        Dim tword As String            '
        Dim aword As Object            '
        Dim tmpName As String          '

        ' Set up excluded words
        Excludes = "[the][a][of][is][to][for][by][be][and][are]"

        ' Find out how to sort
        ByFreq = True
        ans = InputBox("Sort by WORD or by FREQ?", "Sort order", "WORD")
        If ans = "" Then End
        If UCase(ans) = "WORD" Then
            ByFreq = False
        End If

        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        System.Cursor = wdCursorWait
        WordNum = 0
        ttlwds = ActiveDocument.Words.Count

        ' Control the repeat
        For Each aword In ActiveDocument.Words
            SingleWord = Trim(LCase(aword))
            'Out of range?
            If SingleWord < "a" Or SingleWord > "z" Then
                SingleWord = ""
            End If
            'On exclude list?
            If InStr(Excludes, "[" & SingleWord & "]") Then
                SingleWord = ""
            End If
            If Len(SingleWord) > 0 Then
                Found = False
                For j = 1 To WordNum
                    If Words(j) = SingleWord Then
                        Freq(j) = Freq(j) + 1
                        Found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                If Not Found Then
                    WordNum = WordNum + 1
                    Words(WordNum) = SingleWord
                    Freq(WordNum) = 1
                End If
                If WordNum > maxwords - 1 Then
                    j = MsgBox("Too many words.", vbOKOnly)
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            ttlwds = ttlwds - 1
            StatusBar = "Remaining: " & ttlwds & ", Unique: " & WordNum
        Next aword

        ' Now sort it into word order
        For j = 1 To WordNum - 1
            k = j
            For l = j + 1 To WordNum
                If (Not ByFreq And Words(l) < Words(k)) _
                  Or (ByFreq And Freq(l) > Freq(k)) Then k = l
            Next l
            If k <> j Then
                tword = Words(j)
                Words(j) = Words(k)
                Words(k) = tword
                Temp = Freq(j)
                Freq(j) = Freq(k)
                Freq(k) = Temp
            End If
            StatusBar = "Sorting: " & WordNum - j
        Next j

        ' Now write out the results
        tmpName = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName
        Documents.Add Template:=tmpName, NewTemplate:=False
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll
        With Selection
            For j = 1 To WordNum
                .TypeText Text:=Trim(Str(Freq(j))) _
                  & vbTab & Words(j) & vbCrLf
            Next j
        End With
        System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal
        j = MsgBox("There were " & Trim(Str(WordNum)) & _
          " different words ", vbOKOnly, "Finished")
    End Sub
  ```
- You may use <kbd>F5</kbd> in the editor to run/test the macro
- In everyday use you may run the macro `WordFrequency` from the
  [Developer tab](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-the-developer-tab-on-the-ribbon?view=vs-2017)
- For frequent use you may
  [Assign a macro to a ribbon button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c)
  or for easier activation
  [Adding a Macro to the Quick Access Toolbar](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T006011_Adding_a_Macro_to_the_Quick_Access_Toolbar.html).

Test it first on a small document, since on a huge document this macro
will take some time to finish.

Comment: With all due respect, why not just open a language war? No-one wins. VBA didn't arrive in Word until Word 97, not 1993, it's actually a pretty good language, but the question the OP actually asked was "Does Word have anything built-in?" and the answer is actually "No". If the OP wants to ask a question that requires someone to write a whole bunch of VBA, perhaps here is not the place?

Comment: The question is "Does Word have anything built-in?". Your answer clear doesn't address that so why are you posting it?

Comment: For 1993 argue with Wikipedia. VBA is certainly built-in Word and very well integrated. This answer intends to guide the poster in the only solution that doesn't involve installing third-party software. Isn't that the definition of "built-in "?